# How to align two columns in a table | HTML Email Signature

Tags: html, html-email

I'm working on a HTML email signature for our customer. We need to align the two columns at the top and bottom.

- the text at the bottom must bottom align with the social media icons
- and the text at the top must top align with the logo

We have browsed the forums but to no avail.

```html
<table id="escmadbirdies" rules="none" {finalexportlimited-width}="" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:0" width="500">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top" style="border:0">
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td nowrap="" style="white-space:nowrap;border:0;padding-bottom:5px;line-height:20px">
                        <span style="font-family:Avenir;;font-size:20px;color:white;line-height:20px;font-weight:bold;background-color:black;padding-left:4px;padding-right:4px">
                                                            Clare&nbsp;Lavender<br>
                                                        </span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td nowrap="" style="white-space:nowrap;border:0;padding-bottom:15px;line-height:15px">
                        <span style="font-family:Avenir;;font-size:15px;color:white;line-height:15px;background-color:black;padding-left:4px;padding-right:4px">
                                                            <strong>Accounts&nbsp;Manager</strong>
                                                        </span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td nowrap="" style="white-space:nowrap;border:0;padding-bottom:12px;line-height:15px">
                        <span style="font-family:Avenir;;font-size:15px;color:white;line-height:15px;background-color:black;padding-left:3px;padding-right:3px">
                                                            t&nbsp;•&nbsp;1300&nbsp;722&nbsp;896&nbsp;/&nbsp;(02)&nbsp;4732&nbsp;4766<br>
                                                        </span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td nowrap="" style="white-space:nowrap;border:0;padding-bottom:2px;line-height:15px">
                        <span style="font-family:Avenir;;font-size:15px;color:white;line-height:15px;background-color:black;padding-left:3px;padding-right:3px">
                                                            a&nbsp;•&nbsp;Unit&nbsp;6,&nbsp;51&nbsp;York&nbsp;Road&nbsp;Penrith&nbsp;NSW&nbsp;2750<br>
                                                        </span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td nowrap="" style="white-space:nowrap;border:0;padding-bottom:10px;line-height:16px">
                        <span style="font-family:Avenir;;font-size:16px;color:white;line-height:16px;background-color:black;padding-left:3px;padding-right:3px">
                                                            <a href="https://www.whiteriverdesign.com/" target="_blank" style="font-family:Avenir;;font-size:16px;color:white;line-height:18px;text-decoration: none">www.<strong>whiteriverdesign</strong>.com</a> 
                                                        </span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top" style="border:0;padding-left:30px">
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="center" style="white-space:nowrap;border:0;text-align:center">
                        <img src="https://katberg.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/WRD.gif" ; alt="" nosend="1" border="none" height="120" width="120">
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="center" nowrap="" style="white-space:nowrap;border:0;text-align:center">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/WRDCreative" target="_blank"><img src="https://katberg.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Facebook_WRD1.png" ; alt="" nosend="1" border="none" height="20" width="10"></a>
                        &nbsp;
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/WRDCreative/" target="_blank"><img src="https://katberg.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Instagram_WRD1.png" ; alt="" nosend="1" border="none" height="20" width="18"></a>
                        &nbsp;
                        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/wrd" target="_blank"><img src="https://katberg.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/LinkedIn_WRD1.png" ; alt="" nosend="1" border="none" height="20" width="18"></a>
                        &nbsp;
                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/whiteriverdesign" target="_blank"><img src="https://katberg.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Youtube_WRD1.png" ; alt="" nosend="1" border="none" height="20" width="15"></a>
                        &nbsp;
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/wrdcreative" target="_blank"><img src="https://katberg.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Twitter_WRD1.png" ; alt="" nosend="1" border="none" height="20" width="18"></a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ChrisFourie, is not understandable what you want to achieve, Add the current Output and add the expected output with some example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try to use a separate css file.
Flexbox is maybe better for use. Or Grid.

Comment: You've prob been downvoted becaues this is a html email context, and all of those things are banned in many email clients. See caniemail for example

Answer (score 0):

HTML email will be rendered differently depending on the device, email client, operating system and so on. So pixel perfection is not always obtainable.

For desktops, you just need to measure the height of the right side (images), since they are fixed height, and apply extra padding in the middle of the left side.

For example, you could just add some padding-top to the web address like so:

```
<tr>
  <td style="white-space:nowrap;border:0;padding-bottom: 0px;line-height:16px;padding-top: 20px;">
    <span style="font-family:Avenir;;font-size:16px;color:white;line-height:16px;background-color:black;padding-left:3px;padding-right:3px">
      <a href="https://www.whiteriverdesign.com/" target="_blank" style="font-family:Avenir;;font-size:16px;color:white;line-height:18px;text-decoration: none">www.<strong>whiteriverdesign</strong>.com</a> 
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

For mobiles & tablets, you'll probably need to consider stacking the columns (a complete restructure), since there wouldn't be enough space to have both side by side.

Comment: Thank you, I added padding at the top and played around with the white space between the text.

Issue resolved.

Comment: Ok-mark this as the correct answer then please